# Move document in the another folder of same library using power automate workflow

Tags: sharepoint-2013, workflow, powerapps, power-automate, sharepoint-workflow

I am new to the workflows. I have created a workflow where I need to move document which are not modified over one year to another folder of same library.
Source library : AAATestDocument
Destination : AAATestDocument/ArchivedDocuments

It moved document to the "ArchivedDocuments" folder but at last it does check for same folder and throwing error saying **"/sites/TestSite/AAATestDocument/ArchivedDocuments does not exist."**

Any idea how to resolve this issue for folders ? It should check recursively in all folder if it has any.
Here is my workflow.

[image]

here expression is for 1 day to test the flow "startOfDay(addDays(utcNow(),1))"

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add conditions in your flow like the below:

[image]